# iPhone Splash Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Trying to programmatically add a splash image that hangs around for a specified amount of time. I have Default.png already imported into my project, and I see it flicker as the launch image when the simulator launches. I'm not sure how to make Default.png hang around as the splash image.

In AppDelegate.m, inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I do the following:

```
MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc] autorelease];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden: YES];
```

MyViewController as you might suspect, is a subclass of UIViewController, and in the loadView method I do the following:

```
self.mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.view = mainView;
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Then I created SplashScreenViewController, also a subclass of UIViewController, and in the loadView method I do the following:

```
splashView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
```

Finally, back in AppDelegate I have the following after makeKeyAndVisible:

```
SplashScreenViewController *splashScreen = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] init];
splashScreen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[navController presentModalViewController:splashScreen animated:NO];
```

I think I'm just stuck understanding how to tie all the UIViewController subclasses together, and how to reference them from AppDelegate (or whether I should even be doing that), etc. Any tips are appreciated. I can clarify if my question is muddy.

Comment: Have you considered not doing this? It's a violation of Apple's Human Interface Guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html

Comment: I'm not publishing this to the App store, so Apple HIG is not applicable.

Comment: Plenty of apps do it, often in combination with UIProgressView. On its own this won't trigger rejection. But you must not let it sit indefinitely if there is a problem with setup, like no connectivity.

Comment: Why, pray tell, is the Apple HIG not applicable? It's not a set of acceptance criteria, it's advice on how to make good apps.

Comment: I explained in the previous comment why it's not applicable. If nobody other than myself is going to see the result, I'm free to dismiss yours, Apples, or anyone else's guidelines about what is acceptable practice - particularly when the only purpose is teaching myself the inner workings of an app. Your initial comment had value, in the event that I was unaware of the violation (I was aware). Beyond that, you can either answer the question, or not. It's unfortunate to see a prevailing attitude of "you shouldn't even ask how to do something that doesn't conform to an existing standard".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move this to `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`

```
SplashScreenViewController *splashScreen = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] init];
splashScreen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[navController presentModalViewController:splashScreen animated:NO];
```

Or you could do this in you AppDelegate, before `makeKeyAndVisible`

```
splashView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)] autorelease];
splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
[self.window addSubview:splashView];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
```

What's your plan for dismissing the view?

Comment: just going to make a method to remove it, i.e. dismissView

Comment: Then just stick it in the application delegate, no need for another controler (appdelegate itself is a controler).

Comment: Makes sense. Back to the drawing board! Thanks.